# Design a Circuit with Zero-Order Transfer function H(s) > 1

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, circuit-design, design, transfer-function

I know that if I do 2 1K ohm resistors in series, I can just do a voltage divider to get Vout/Vin = R2/(R1+R2) = 0.5. But if I want to get a transfer function of 3, what components would I use?

Comment: An operational amplifier for example, opamp for short. Internet is full of "opamp applications"

Comment: What if I'm only allowed to use resistors, capacitors, and inductors?

Comment: @Jeff: With only passive components an over unity transfer function  is not possible that works on any frequency.

Comment: ohh I see. Thank you!

Comment: @Bart Around the resonance frequency the *passive components* capacitor and inductor can give a gain > 1.

Comment: @Huisman, I know that. This is being used in impedance matching circuits. The question however asks for a transfer function without poles or zeroes and a gain of 9.5 dB. That is why my comment mentioned *any* frequency.

Answer (score 1):

s-domain analysis is unitless, so you are free to describe *any* transfer function.

You may simply provide your instructor with a resistor with a resistance greater than \$ 1 \; \Omega\$, along with the current to voltage transfer function of your resistor.

You could also employ an ideal transformer with secondary:primary turns ratio greater than 1.

Comment: Two methods that solve the problem.

Comment: Note that the original question (modified since then) asked for H(s) = 3. No unit was specified, so a transconductance or transresistance device is probably not what was asked for. Also note that the system has to be zero order, which includes DC.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do (a passive network with gain > 1 independent of frequency) is not possible if you use only passive components. If you use resistors, one of them will have to be negative. The last time I checked, negative resistors were not yet invented.

It is possible to simulate negative resistances, using a device called a gyrator. A gyrator always contains at least one active component, and exhibits frequency dependency.

You can make a circuit that has a gain > 1 using inductors and capacitors. This works, because capacitive reactance are negative, but they are also frequency dependant. Therefore this kind of circuit will only work around a certain resonant frequency. It is  called an impedance matching circuit.

Also keep in mind that for all practical purposes, a fully frequency independent device is not possible. There will always be parasitic capacitances and inductances.